# setting up linked list Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm working on some basic linked list stuff, like insert, delete, go to the front or end of the list, and basically i understand the concept of all of that stuff once i have the list i guess but im having trouble setting up the list. I was wondering of you guys could tell me if im going in the right direction. (mostly just the setup) this is what i have so far:

```
public class List {

private int size;
private List linkedList;
List head;
List cur;
List next;

/**
 * Creates an empty list.
 * @pre 
 * @post
 */
public List(){
    linkedList = new List();
    this.head = null;
    cur = head; 
}

/**
 * Delete the current element from this list. The element after the deleted element becomes the new current. 
 * If that's not possible, then the element before the deleted element becomes the new current. 
 * If that is also not possible, then you need to recognize what state the list is in and define current accordingly.
 * Nothing should be done if a delete is not possible.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */ 
public void delete(){

}

/**
 * Get the value of the current element. If this is not possible, throw an IllegalArgumentException.
 * @pre the list is not empty
 * @post
 * @return value of the current element.
 */
public char get(){
    return getItem(cur);
}

/**
 * Go to the last element of the list. If this is not possible, don't change the cursor.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */
public void goLast(){
    while (cur.next != null){
        cur = cur.next;
    }
}

/**
 * Advance the cursor to the next element. If this is not possible, don't change the cursor.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */
public void goNext(){
    if(cur.next != null){
        cur = cur.next;}
    //else do nothing
}

/**
 * Retreat the cursor to the previous element. If this is not possible, don't change the cursor.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */
public void goPrev(){

}

/**
 * Go to top of the list. This is the position before the first element.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */
public void goTop(){

}

/**
 * Go to first element of the list. If this is not possible, don't change the cursor.
 * @pre
 * @post
 */
public void goFirst(){

}

/**
 * Insert the given parameter after the current element. The newly inserted element becomes the current element.
 * @pre
 * @post
 * @param newVal : value to insert after the current element.
 */
public void insert(char newVal){
    cur.setItem(newVal);
    size++;
}

/**
 * Determines if this list is empty. Empty means this list has no elements.
 * @pre
 * @post
 * @return true if the list is empty.
 */
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return head == null;
}

/**
 * Determines the size of the list. The size of the list is the number of elements in the list.
 * @pre
 * @post
 * @return size which is the number of elements in the list.
 */
public int size(){
    return size;
}


public class Node {

    private char item;
    private Node next;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(char item) {
            this.item = item;
    }

    public Node(char item, Node next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public char getItem() {
        return this.item;
    }

    public void setItem(char item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

}

I got the node class alright (well i think it works alright), but is it necessary to even have that class? or can i go about it without even using it (just curious).
And for example on the method get() in the list class can i not call that getItem() method from the node class because it's getting an error even though i thought that was the whole point for the node class.

bottom line i just wanna make sure im setting up the list right.

Thanks for any help guys, im new to linked list's so bear with me!

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment I did 10 years ago.

Comment: Why is head, etc all lists? this is messed up :(

Comment: is it that bad? :( I'm trying to understand but from what everyone is saying and you sounds like i have no hope!

Answer (score 0):

`head`, `cur` and `last` should be `Node`s, not `List`s.

Also you should declare `Node` as `Node<T>`, then it can contain any type of object (instead of just a `char`). You'd have to replace all the word `char` with `T`, and your class `List` should therefore also be `List<T>`.

`delete` actually needs to remove an element, it doesn't right now.

Also, you've given your `List` iterator functionality (with `cur`)... you would probably be better off separating that functionality in a separate class (or rename your list to "IteratedList") or something.

Otherwise a pretty decent start!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I know delete has to delete haha that wasnt a lame attempt at it that was me not doing it yet! And also it's okay about the <T> because i ONLY need char's. It's just a simple list to do these simple tasks. Could you elaborate more on the CUR situation, because i need it in this class as a way to traverse and such(like is it wrong i am using it there?).

Comment: Why does a `List` need to know how to traverse itself? A `List` is a bunch of things. That's like designing a notebook to come with a pen. Or, you could provide a notebook, and a pen separately. The way Java does it, `java.util.List` (the notebook, effectively) has a method `.iterator()` which gives you an `Iterator` object (the pen) that does that job for you. Of course you might want to provide a "notebook + pen" for your users...

Comment: Starting to make sense, So if i were to not use cur then how would i do stuff like go to the next element (cur=cur.next) or the whole point of the get method is to return the current element, so how would that work without a current?

Comment: You wouldn't have a `get` method in your `List` class... or you could have `getAt(int index)`. But you could do `Node head = myList.getHeadNode()`, then do `current = head; do { // stuff } while ((current = current.next) != null);` to iterate through the list

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something very important - some more comments. In particular, I think you should write a comment block explaining how the list is to be represented, including what it should look like when empty, with one element, and with more than one element. Work through a few scenarios with paper and pencil.

When you **know** what an empty list should look like, and are sure that representation does what you need, the constructor will be really easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand. You're making a linked list, so a List object should somehow use Node objects, right?  you want to have the list  represented by a head (node), current (node), next (also a node) as well the size (int).

I don't believe it makes sense to have the `private List linkedList;`. To get a better understanding why it doesn't work, try by hand to initialize a list, you will find yourself initializing a new list, which will lead to intializing a new list, ... etc. That's one reason why you get an error regardless of other problems I told you about in the design itself.

Keep working on that. You will also need to enhance the implementation of delete as well. To delete a node from a list, you don't just decrease the size, you should make its previous node references its next node. something like `prev.next = node.next`. But keep working, you'll learn a lot in this exercise.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! Like i said to the other guy i should have commented that out in the delete method haha i wasnt done, im not thaaaaat boneheaded :p So is what your saying about the "list head, cur, next and LinkedList" unnecessary? the reason i used those was so i could say stuff like cur.next and such, or did i just do that all wrong? Like instead of saying that do i use the node class methods, like cur.setNext(next)?

Comment: it really depends what do you mean by "next" and "curr", what will use use them for? I didn't say that they are unnecessary (if I was going to implement this class, I would use something similar), I said they should be nodes and not lists.

Comment: I guess then i wont use them for anything, I just thought you had to declare them some how in order to say stuff like in public void goLast() "`cur = cur.next`" I mean now that i think of it i guess cur is just a pointer to keep track of where I am in the List

Comment: You need to know first what are the functionality wanted from the class you're implementing before rushing to the code.